# Pandas: Difference of time columns returns -1 days

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe which has two-time columns (`dtype = timedelta64[ns]`)
 
which looks like:

```
START_TIME      RESTORE_TIME
17:17:00        18:46:00
20:07:00        00:44:00
20:07:00        00:45:00
14:16:00        15:50:00
14:16:00        17:55:00
```

I created another column which takes the difference of `RESTORE_TIME` from `START_TIME`. I used the following command:

```
df['Diff']=df['RESTORE_TIME'] - df2['START_TIME']
```

My output dataframe looks like:

```
  START_TIME      RESTORE_TIME      Diff
  17:17:00        18:46:00          01:29:00
  20:07:00        00:44:00 -1 days +04:37:00
  20:07:00        00:45:00 -1 days +04:38:00
  14:16:00        15:50:00          01:34:00
  14:16:00        17:55:00          03:39:00
```

I am not sure why does `Diff` column shows `-1 days` in some values? When I perform a certain calculations on Diff column it did not return the desired value. For example, if I take the mean of `Diff` column (by using the command `np.mean(df['Diff'])`, it returns `Timedelta('-1 days +17:35:24')` which is clearly not the case. Could anyone guide me on how to rectify the issue?

Comment: Are you sure your columns are of type `timedelta64[ns]`? that would not make immediately sense to me since you don't know the reference date in that case. Type `datetime.time` would not make it much better, since it has the same problem of missing reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to illustrate what's happening here, let's create a dummy `df` with columns of type `timedelta64[ns]`:

```
from datetime import timedelta
import pandas as pd

# example df with time columns
df = pd.DataFrame({'START_TIME': pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(['17:17:00','20:07:00','20:07:00','14:16:00','14:16:00'])).dt.time,
                   'RESTORE_TIME': pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(['18:46:00','00:44:00','00:45:00','15:50:00','17:55:00'])).dt.time})
# to timedelta
df = df.applymap(lambda t: timedelta(hours=t.hour, minutes=t.minute, seconds=t.second))
```

if you have a look at the total_seconds of the timedelta, it becomes clear what is happening if you take the difference of the two columns:

```
df.applymap(lambda t: t.total_seconds())
#    START_TIME  RESTORE_TIME
# 0     62220.0       67560.0
# 1     72420.0        2640.0
# 2     72420.0        2700.0
# 3     51360.0       57000.0
# 4     51360.0       64500.0
```

e.g. `2640.0 - 72420.0` is obviously negative, and '-1 days +04:37:00' experessed as a timedelta.

Similar to @Ehsan's answer, you could apply a simple function to add one day in case 'START_TIME' > 'RESTORE_TIME':

```
def timedelta_diff(t0, t1):
    """
    calculate difference between two timedeltas t0 and t1.
    if t1 < t0, assume that 1 day has to be added to t1.
    """
    if t1 < t0:
        t1 += timedelta(days=1)
    return t1-t0

df['DIFF'] = df.apply(lambda x: timedelta_diff(x.START_TIME, x.RESTORE_TIME), axis=1)
# df['DIFF']
# 0   01:29:00
# 1   04:37:00
# 2   04:38:00
# 3   01:34:00
# 4   03:39:00
# Name: DIFF, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Answer (score 1):

In case of cross midnight you need to add following to your code:

```
from datetime import timedelta
if df['Diff'].days < 0:
    df['Diff'] = timedelta(days=0,
                seconds=df['Diff'].seconds, microseconds=df['Diff'].microseconds)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is right. It happens because the second column (RESTORE_TIME) for these two rows shows a time for after midnight. That means a new day has already started. 
I can think of using conditions to avoid this, for example you can say

```
if df2['START_TIME']< df['RESTORE_TIME']:
   df['Diff']= df2['START_TIME'] - df['RESTORE_TIME'] 
else:
   df['Diff']= df['RESTORE_TIME'] - df2['START_TIME']
```